# How to Create Background Image Size for tablet 7 inch in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

We knew in android we can create images in particular size and put in drawable or mipmap foders.

In android for managing background  image size we have these sizes :

```
Background       240*320  320*480 480*800 768*1280 1080 *1920  1440*2560
```

our problem is we have created all of sizes and put in drawable folders, in all size works but just doesn't work in tablet 7inch

for tablet 7 we have tested `768*1280` px  and `640x960` px size but doesnt work and quality is very low

What is the best solution for Image background in Tablet 7 inch?

Thank You

Comment: Could you please offer more details who you integrate your resources.

Comment: which offer is good?

Comment: anybody could'nt find a solution?

Comment: We need more information about how you integrate your resources.

Comment: it is very clear. we put files in drawabl folders as same names,but just in tablet 7 quality is not good. i need aproache for this issue